# Detect if page successfully rendered in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails, web

I have a grails application where i have to detect if page is rendered successfully.

So, if I have `render view: "mypage"`, I want to know if this page was rendered successfully by tomcat. Whether it reached user or not is not concern here. That is another part which can be tracked by using javascript events.

The solution that comes to my mind is using error controller and url mapping to map any issue like 404 or 500 to one controller but that controller is somewhat generic and will be handling multiple issues and not just this one.

So, Is it possible to exclusively know for this `render` call if it was rendered properly or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching a filter to the action with the [afterView](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filterTypes) filter type.  The documentation mentions that the first argument is an Exception, so if the first argument is null, then the render succeeded.  (Also note that the documentation mentions afterView is called before the SiteMesh layout is applied, if that matters for this particular problem)